# Работа с Unicode в Cython

Tags: c++, python, unicode, cython

Имеется скрипт, написанный на Cython, который принимает на вход массив C++ строк, анализирует их с помощью pymorphy2 и обрабатывает результаты анализа. В процессе сборки данный скрипт транслируется в исходный код на C++ с помощью следующей команды:

`cython ${SCRIPT_FILENAME} -o "morph-analyzer.cpp" -2`

В данном скрипте определена функция, в которой осуществляется взаимодействие с pymorphy2:

```
cdef analyzeToken(const UnicodeString tok, vector[pair[UnicodeString, vector[shared_ptr[AnalysisResult]]]] &analysis_results):
    cdef vector[shared_ptr[AnalysisResult]] res_for_tok    
    cdef shared_ptr[AnalysisResult] analysis_res

    cdef string utf8_str
    tok.toUTF8String(utf8_str)
    morph_results = morph.parse((utf8_str.c_str()).decode('UTF-8'))

    cdef unsigned propMask
    for morph_result in morph_results:
        analysis_res = make_shared[AnalysisResult]()
        if morph_result.score > 0.1:
            deref(analysis_res).normalForm = UnicodeString(morph_result.normal_form.encode('UTF-8'))
            propMask = 0 
            if morph_result.tag.POS is not None:
                deref(analysis_res).partOfSpeech = UnicodeString(morph_result.tag.POS.encode('UTF-8'))
            if 'Name' in morph_result.tag:
                propMask |= FIRST_NAME
            if 'Patr' in morph_result.tag:
                propMask |= PATR
            if 'Surn' in morph_result.tag:
                propMask |= SECOND_NAME
            if 'Init' in morph_result.tag:
                propMask |= INIT
            if 'Geox' in morph_result.tag:
                propMask |= GEOX
            deref(analysis_res).nameCharMask = propMask
        else:
            deref(analysis_res).normalForm = tok
        res_for_tok.push_back(analysis_res)
     analysis_results.push_back(pair[UnicodeString, vector[shared_ptr[AnalysisResult]]](tok, res_for_tok))
```

Входная строка, которую нужно проанализировать, подается на вход данной функции как объект класса `UnicodeString` (из библиотеки [icu4c](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/)) под именем `tok`. Первым делом производится преобразование переданной строки в объект класса std::string в кодировке utf-8:

```
cdef string utf8_str
tok.toUTF8String(utf8_str)
```

Далее, нужно передать эту строку на вход функции `pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer.parse()`, которая принимает родные строки из Python в формате Unicode. Чтобы преобразовать имеющуюся utf-8 строку в нужный формат, вызывается метод `bytes.decode('UTF-8')`.

При обработке результатов от pymoprhy2 производится обратное преобразование полученной строки в формат utf-8 с помощью функции `encode('UTF-8')`, после чего результат передается на вход конструктору `UnicodeString`.

Приведенный выше код корректно работает в системе Linux при использовании Python 2.7.13 and Cython 0.25.2. Однако в Windows при использовании тех же версий Python и Cython строки каким-то образом искажаются, из-за чего pymorphy2 оказывается не в состоянии их обработать. Ниже приведен результат искажения:

`Current token: Original word: нижес▒едующем, normal form: ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒␰▒`

Должно быть так:

`Current token: Original word: нижеследующем, normal form: нижеследующий`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема. Хотел бы еще раз подчеркнуть тот факт, что проявляется она только при работе в Windows (версия 8.1).

**Update:**

Функция `analyzeToken` вызывается из другой функции, определенной в том же скрипте:

```
cdef public analyzeTokens(const vector[UnicodeString] &tokens, map[UnicodeString, vector[shared_ptr[AnalysisResult]]] &analysis_results):
for i in xrange(tokens.size()):
    analyzeToken(tokens[i], analysis_results)
```

которая, в свою очередь, вызывается уже из C++ кода

```
    std::map<UnicodeString, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AnalysisResult>>> analysisResults;
    analyzeTokens(plainTokens, analysisResults);
```

где `plainTokens` - `std::vector<UnicodeString>`. Ключевое слово `public` в сигнатуре функции заставляет `Cython` создавать заголовочный файл, содержащий ее объявление.

**Update2:**

Изначально текстовые данные считываются из файла:

```
static bool readAllTextFromFile(const std::string &filename, UnicodeString &outText) {
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    if (ifs.fail()) {
        std::cerr << "Error: failed to open " << filename << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    std::string text {std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()};

    outText = UnicodeString(text.c_str());

    return true;
}
```

Далее считанные текстовые данные проходят некоторую структурную обработку (разбиваются на массивы строк с помощью регулярных выражений) и подаются на вход функции `analyzeTokens`:

```
std::vector<UnicodeString> plainSentences;
split_unistring(plainText, {"\\?","\\.","\\!"}, plainSentences);
for (auto &plainSentence : plainSentences) {
    Logger::getLogger() << plainSentence << std::endl;
    std::vector<UnicodeString> plainTokens;
    split_unistring(plainSentence, {"\\s","\\;","\\:","\\,"}, plainTokens);
    Sentence currentSentence;

    std::map<UnicodeString, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AnalysisResult>>> analysisResults;
    analyzeTokens(plainTokens, analysisResults);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что у винды не `utf-8` кодировка, соответсвенно не работает, почитайте про кодировки винды и нормализацию, добавьте определение кодировок

Comment: А откуда строка изначально попадает в программу?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Добавил в первый пост информацию касательно вашего вопроса.

Comment: @IgorSergeevich Не могли бы вы пояснить, что подразумевается под кодировкой винды? Я полагал, что UnicodeString предоставляет достаточный уровень абстракции. UTF-8 строку мы получаем именно оттуда, из которой потом производим преобразование в родную строку Python.

Comment: Если в программу строка приходит из консоли, например, то в Linux это будет строка в кодировке utf-8, а в Windows в cp866. В обоих случаях её можно будет сохранить в UnicodeString, но во втором вы получите на выходе крякозяблы.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Разве [UnicodeString::toUTF8String()](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#a64317c339e58e8b6135bd4341c6ccfd2) не должна выдать мне именно UTF-8 строку не зависимо от того, из каких входных данных она была сформирована? Вся суть использования `icu` как раз заключалась в том, чтобы хранить строки в платформо-независимой абстракции и конвертировать их в нужную кодировку при необходимости.

Comment: Он и выдаёт utf-8 строку, но её содержимое может сильно различается  от того, какой была исходная кодировка. Поэтому я интересуюсь полным путём строки от входа в программу до выхода.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev И строки приходят не из консоли, а (по крайней мере в данном конкретном случае) из текстового файла с кодировкой UTF-8.

Comment: А считываются они из этого файла как?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev добавил описание считывания текстовых данных.

Comment: Есть предположение: попробуйте задать локаль файловому потоку - `ifs.imbue(std::locale("ru_RU.UTF8"));`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev

Благодарю, вы были правы по поводу того, что строка изначально не `utf-8`. Проблема решилась выставлением дефолтной кодировки для `ICU`

`ucnv_setDefaultName("UTF-8");`